# Stuck on build JSon for ZigBee devices

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, zigbee

Since commax doesnt have any APIs, support, and other sort of help, im trying to build my IoT house with adding unsupported devices manually. But now im stuck on manage Zigbee dimmer to devices.
Whats wrong:

```
    I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): CMD : ZIGBEE_CMD_ACK  -------------------------------
E/PAM_HONG( 2677): psoapUrl = http://127.0.0.1:29870
I/PAM     ( 3332): Subscribe Success http://127.0.0.1:29872
I/AdapterService( 2677): PAM DSS SubscriberThread setSubcribeEvent_while : 127.0.0.1:29872
D/Scene   ( 3145): .(ForLocalService.java:517) onStartCommand(): onStartCommand
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): command_JoinEnable:0100000000000028;, JoinTimer = 40 sec
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Switch Cmd == FALSE
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): send data = 0100000000000028;
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): RX : fa000000000000000000000000000000000000000100;
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Zigbee Msg Received(45) [[
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): CMD          = 0xFA
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): ID           = 0x0000
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Address      = 0x00
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): EP           = 0x0000
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Profile      = 0x0000
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Cluster      = 0x0000
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Attribute    = 0x0000
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): DataSize     = 0x00
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Value                = 0x0000000000000001
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): RSSI         = 0x 0
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332):  ]]
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): CMD : ZIGBEE_CMD_ACK  -------------------------------
W/ProcessStats( 1888): Skipping unknown process pid 10433
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): RX : 01ffff882bffffffffffffff0800158d0004769fb2ff;
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Zigbee Msg Received(45) [[
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): CMD          = 0x01
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): ID           = 0xFFFF
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Address      = 0x882B
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): EP           = 0x00FF
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Profile      = 0xFFFF
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Cluster      = 0xFFFF
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Attribute    = 0xFFFF
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): DataSize     = 0x08
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Value                = 0x00158D0004769FB2
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): MacAddr              = 00158d0004769fb2
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): RSSI         = 0xFF
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332):  ]]
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): CMD : ZIGBEE_JOINNODE
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): MacAddr              = 00158d0004769fb2
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sql_DB_addreesCheck()
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sqlite3_open
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sql = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ZigbeeDevice WHERE Addr=34859;
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sql_DB_macAddreesCheck()
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sqlite3_open
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sql = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ZigbeeDevice WHERE MAC='00158d0004769fb2';
D/dalvikvm( 1888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1707K, 20% free 8654K/10752K, paused 51ms, total 51ms
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): RX : 040210882b0bc05e0006ffff00000000000000000044;
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Zigbee Msg Received(45) [[
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): CMD          = 0x04
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): ID           = 0x0210
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Address      = 0x882B
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): EP           = 0x000B
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Profile      = 0xC05E
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Cluster      = 0x0006
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Attribute    = 0xFFFF
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): DataSize     = 0x00
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Value                = 0x0000000000000000
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): RSSI         = 0x44
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332):  ]]
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): CMD : ZIGBEE_DESCRIPTION_REPORT / m_addModeflag[1]
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): ADD sub device count = 0
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): T_str        = switchBinary
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): T_IDstr = unknown
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): T_count = 0
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sql_DB_subDevice_check()
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sqlite3_open
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sql = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ZigbeeDevice WHERE Addr=34859 AND profile=49246 AND cluster=6 AND EP=11;
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): addDeviceFanc() Mac(409691A8)
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): subUuid      = a61785b2-33c0-4bc2-91b7-f7a92df610cf
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): type         = readWrite
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sort         = switchBinary
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): funcComand   = report
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): value        = off
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): RX : 040210882b0bc05e0008ffff00000000000000000044;
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Zigbee Msg Received(45) [[
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): CMD          = 0x04
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): ID           = 0x0210
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Address      = 0x882B
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): EP           = 0x000B
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Profile      = 0xC05E
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Cluster      = 0x0008
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Attribute    = 0xFFFF
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): DataSize     = 0x00
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Value                = 0x0000000000000000
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): RSSI         = 0x44
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332):  ]]
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): CMD : ZIGBEE_DESCRIPTION_REPORT / m_addModeflag[1]
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): ADD sub device count = 1
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): T_str        = switchDimmer
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): T_IDstr = unknown
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): T_count = 1
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sql_DB_subDevice_check()
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sqlite3_open
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sql = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ZigbeeDevice WHERE Addr=34859 AND profile=49246 AND cluster=8 AND EP=11;
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): addDeviceFanc() Mac(409691A8)
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): subUuid      = 3b40c76e-b462-4fd9-95db-e2608cd1d214
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): type         = readWrite
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sort         = switchDimmer
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): funcComand   = report
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): value        = 0
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): precision    = 0
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): scale                = %
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): RX : 040210882b0bc05e0300ffff00000000000000000044;
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Zigbee Msg Received(45) [[
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): CMD          = 0x04
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): ID           = 0x0210
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Address      = 0x882B
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): EP           = 0x000B
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Profile      = 0xC05E
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Cluster      = 0x0300
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Attribute    = 0xFFFF
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): DataSize     = 0x00
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Value                = 0x0000000000000000
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): RSSI         = 0x44
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332):  ]]
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): CMD : ZIGBEE_DESCRIPTION_REPORT / m_addModeflag[1]
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): ADD sub device count = 2
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): T_str        = colour
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): T_IDstr = unknown
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): T_count = 2
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sql_DB_subDevice_check()
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sqlite3_open
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sql = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ZigbeeDevice WHERE Addr=34859 AND profile=49246 AND cluster=768 AND EP=11;
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): addDeviceFanc() Mac(409691A8)
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): subUuid      = 94137451-9f60-4655-ba5a-c0ab8884436f
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): type         = readWrite
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sort         = colour
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): funcComand   = report
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): value        = off
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): RX : 040210882b0bc05e1000ffff00000000000000000044;
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Zigbee Msg Received(45) [[
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): CMD          = 0x04
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): ID           = 0x0210
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Address      = 0x882B
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): EP           = 0x000B
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Profile      = 0xC05E
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Cluster      = 0x1000
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Attribute    = 0xFFFF
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): DataSize     = 0x00
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Value                = 0x0000000000000000
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): RSSI         = 0x44
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332):  ]]
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): CMD : ZIGBEE_DESCRIPTION_REPORT / m_addModeflag[1]
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): ADD sub device count = 3
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): T_str        = Touch link
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): T_IDstr = unknown
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): T_count = 3
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sql_DB_subDevice_check()
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sqlite3_open
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): sql = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ZigbeeDevice WHERE Addr=34859 AND profile=49246 AND cluster=4096 AND EP=11;
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): addDeviceFanc() Mac(409691A8)
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): RX : 040210882b0bc05e0019ffff00000000000000000044;
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Zigbee Msg Received(45) [[
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): CMD          = 0x04
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): ID           = 0x0210
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Address      = 0x882B
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): EP           = 0x000B
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Profile      = 0xC05E
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Cluster      = 0x0019
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Attribute    = 0xFFFF
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): DataSize     = 0x00
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Value                = 0x0000000000000000
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): RSSI         = 0x44
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332):  ]]
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): CMD : ZIGBEE_DESCRIPTION_REPORT / m_addModeflag[1]
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): ADD sub device count = 4
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Unsupported Device in ZIGBEE_DESCRIPTION_REPORT Cluster(0x0019)
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): RX : 050210882b00c05e8002000002000000000000117e4a;
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Zigbee Msg Received(45) [[
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): CMD          = 0x05
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): ID           = 0x0210
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Address      = 0x882B
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): EP           = 0x0000
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Profile      = 0xC05E
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Cluster      = 0x8002
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Attribute    = 0x0000
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): DataSize     = 0x02
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Value                = 0x000000000000117E
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): RSSI         = 0x4A
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332):  ]]
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): CMD : ZIGBEE_MANUFACTURE
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): manufacturer_check() >> Unknown manufacturer1
E/PAM     ( 3332): @@ ZIGBEE Manucture Check Error [1]
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): command_JoinEnable:010000000000001E;, JoinTimer = 30 sec
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Switch Cmd == FALSE
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): send data = 010000000000001E;
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): RX : fa000000000000000000000000000000000000000100;
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Zigbee Msg Received(45) [[
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): CMD          = 0xFA
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): ID           = 0x0000
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Address      = 0x00
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): EP           = 0x0000
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Profile      = 0x0000
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Cluster      = 0x0000
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Attribute    = 0x0000
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): DataSize     = 0x00
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): Value                = 0x0000000000000001
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332): RSSI         = 0x 0
I/PAZIGBEE( 3332):  ]]
```

Thats log from trying to add manage of zigbee RGB light

What i add to SQLite

table RootDevice

```
{"command":"addReport","object":{"rootUuid":"8fbb1d52-be94-44d8-b54e-56785faaf0f7","rootDevice":"dimmer","information": {"comType": "Zigbee", "manufacture": "HEIMAN", "product": "light"}, "commaxDevice": "light", "visible": "true", "subDevice":[{"value":"0","subUuid":"3b40c76e-b462-4fd9-95db-e2608cd1d214","sort":"switchDimmer","funcCommand":"report","precision":"0", "option1": "0", "option2": "100", "type":"readWrite", "subVisible": "true", "ifRunvisible": "true", "other_subcount": "1", "other_sort[1]": "switchBinary", "other_subUuid[1]": "a61785b2-33c0-4bc2-91b7-f7a92df610cf", "other_value[1]": "off", "other_precision[1]": "0", "other_option1[1]": "0", "other_option2[1]": "100", "controller": "0"}]}}
```

table subDevice

1.

```
{"command": "report", "object": {"rootDevice": "dimmer", "rootUuid": "8fbb1d52-be94-44d8-b54e-56785faaf0f7", "commaxDevice": "light", "subDevice": [{"subUuid": "a61785b2-33c0-4bc2-91b7-f7a92df610cf", "type": "readWrite", "funcCommand": "report", "sort": "switchBinary", "value": "off"}]}}
```

2. 

```
{"command": "report", "object": {"rootDevice": "dimmer", "rootUuid": "8fbb1d52-be94-44d8-b54e-56785faaf0f7", "commaxDevice": "light", "subDevice": [{"subUuid": "3b40c76e-b462-4fd9-95db-e2608cd1d214", "type": "readWrite", "funcCommand": "report", "sort": "switchDimmer", "value": "0", "precision": "0", "option1": "0", "option2": "100"}]}}
```

https://github.com/chechea/Cherryblossom/blob/master/IPHomeIoT/Control/app/src/main/java/com/commax/control/Card_list/Card_DimmerSwitch.java

Thats is a card of `DimmerSwitch` and I don't understand why I got NullPointerException when I try to launch it.

Anyway, I still don't understand what parameter I need to give as "scale", because I need send to ZigBee "%" as scale.
With my realisation it only changes values like value from 0 to 100 without sending a scale type, so my dimmer doesnt run on full light.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution:

for table rootDevice

```
{"command":"addReport","object":{"rootUuid":"8fbb1d52-be94-44d8-b54e-56785faaf0f7","rootDevice":"dimmer","information":{"comType":"Zigbee","manufacture":"HEIMAN","product":"light"},"commaxDevice":"light","visible":"true","subDevice":[{"subUuid":"3b40c76e-b462-4fd9-95db-e2608cd1d214","value":"0","sort":"switchDimmer","funcCommand":"report","precision":"0","option1":"10","option2":"100","type":"readWrite","subVisible":"true","ifRunvisible":"true"},{"subUuid":"a61785b2-33c0-4bc2-91b7-f7a92df610cf","value":"off","sort":"switchBinary"}]}}
```

for table subDevice on both devices (switch and dimmer)

```
{"command":"report","object":{"rootDevice":"dimmer","rootUuid":"8fbb1d52-be94-44d8-b54e-56785faaf0f7","commaxDevice":"light","subDevice":[{"subUuid":"3b40c76e-b462-4fd9-95db-e2608cd1d214","value":"0","sort":"switchDimmer","funcCommand":"report","precision":"0","option1":"10","option2":"100","type":"readWrite","subVisible":"true","ifRunvisible":"true"},{"subUuid":"a61785b2-33c0-4bc2-91b7-f7a92df610cf","value":"off","sort":"switchBinary"}]}}
```